# Create function to count occurrences within groups in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, sum, subset

I have a dataset with a unique ID for groups of patients called  `match_no` and i want to count how many patients got sick in two different years by running a loop function to count the occurrences in a large dataset

```
for (i in db$match_no){(with(db, sum(db$TBHist16 == 1 & db$match_no == i))}
```

This is my attempt. I need i to cycle through each of the match numbers and count how many TB occurrences there was.

Can anyone correct my formula please.

Example here

```
df1 <- data.frame(Match_no = c(1, 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4,4, 5,5,5,5,5),
                  var1 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1))
```

I want to count how many 1 values there are in each match number.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with some data and an expected result

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/12400385

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Simple summary of all `Match_no` values:

   ```r
   xtabs(~var1 + Match_no, data = df1)
   #     Match_no
   # var1 1 2 3 4 5
   #    0 2 2 1 3 1
   #    1 3 3 4 2 4
   ```
2. Same as 1, but with a subset:

   ```r
   xtabs(~ Match_no, data = subset(df1, var1 == 1))
   # Match_no
   # 1 2 3 4 5 
   # 3 3 4 2 4
   ```
3. Results in a frame:

   ```r
   aggregate(var1 ~ Match_no, data = subset(df1, var1 == 1), FUN = length)
   #   Match_no var1
   # 1        1    3
   # 2        2    3
   # 3        3    4
   # 4        4    2
   # 5        5    4
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In base `R` you can use `aggregate` and `sum`:

```
aggregate(var1 ~ Match_no, data = df1, FUN = sum)

  Match_no var1
1        1    3
2        2    3
3        3    4
4        4    2
5        5    4
```